# Google Recognizes My Device When I Login Via Tor Browser

Tags: anonymity, cookies

I have used the Tor Browser to login to my google account multiple times, and in each instance I am marked as using the same device in "Recently used devices," even if I am connecting via a different exit node. 
When I connected via the Tor Browser running inside a virtual machine, Google correctly identified me as using a different device.

Scripts are enabled globally in my browser, and cookies are allowed but obviously deleted at the end of a session.

Does my browser have some vulnerability that allows Google to recognize me each time I login?

Comment: My guess is that it's likely a change of fingerprint, for example the browser window size would probably differ between the VM and your desktop and can be detected by javascript. It's suggested they use a series of different methods to identify the device and determine if it is significantly different from previous fingerprints. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552810/how-does-google-recognize-a-trusted-device-with-2-step-verification

Comment: @canonizingironize Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.